# Use gradle-ospackage-plugin in a maven project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, rpm, rpmbuild

I Need to user **gradle-ospackage-plugin** in **maven** project. Examples found googling are done with gradle.

Can someone help or point to a resource?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i'm using maven, i finally switch to **rpm-maven-plugin**. To use it in windows environment however, you'll need to use cygwin and install rpm packages.

Hope this will help another guy in the future.